Android Studio USB-connected device won't run app
I'm attempting to connect my phone via USB cable.  Android Studio recognizes my device but the app doesn't open / run on my connected phone.  The articles or answers I've found are about how to get AStudio to recognize your device, which, as mentioned, it does.
I'm trying to run the sample app that comes with AStudio. When I hit Play / Run, I get the following output:

Positional arguments: []
Process finished with exit code 0

I also get a message that says "Flutter daemon terminated. Try restarting Android Studio".
I'm using Windows 10 and connecting a Moto G4 running Nougat (Android 7.0 OS). I have USB Debugging enabled and have tried with PTP and with Charging. I believe my driver is up to date. I feel like I'm missing something totally obvious! Is there an extra step I need to take? Apologies if this is a noob question but I can't seem to figure it out.

Check device manager of Windows if the adb interface is properly configured. If activated on the phone it doesn't mater if you select charge only, MTP or PTP, ADB will always be available.

if restarting android studio and PC didn't help, It could be Android Debug Server (adb) cannot debug properly.Now your description is not enough to provide you with the correct solution .Need to see the whole Daemon log.
Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger: Set "Use existing manually managed server" with port 5038.
After that if you use Linux:
--path-to-android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
--path-to-android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
Solution :https://9to5answer.com/the-flutter-daemon-has-been-terminated
